# How to get steady time on an Atmel xPlained SAMA5D3

Tags: linux, debian, time, clock

I'm running Debian Jessie from an sdcard on an Atmel xPlained SAMA5D3 SBC. I have a python program which samples another device via serial line. Said device has a pretty reliable 20s countdown clock. I found the computed cycle times were moving around quite a bit.

This led to discovering that systemd-timesyncd was adjusting the clock by 0.5s-1.0s every 32s. It doesn't seem to adjust the tickrate, but just keeps offsetting. Since it's so much, it never backs off and keeps hitting it every 32s. I found that the full ntp packages and openntpd behaved similarily.

So I turned systemd-timesyncd off. And found that at that point, I was steadily losing about 1.5s per minute.

This led me to install ntpdate and adjtimex. I wrote a cron job which did an ntpdate every 10 minutes and logged those results to a file. By using the equation

```
tickAdjust = ntpAdjustmentMilliseconds / 10minutes
```

I could use adjtimex -t to adjust the tick value. With a value of 10158, the 10 minutes updates became very small, hovering on both sides of 0.

So my question at this point is, what to do? I've learned a bit about Linux and time, but I seem to have more questions now. I don't know if that value of 10158 is just way out there or acceptable?Should I just write a little python program that analyzes my logs and does as I did manually? Why is it so wildly skewed initially that systemd-timesyncd can't adjust it? Is my kernel even pointing at the right clock source? The user-guide says there are two processor clocks, but the following shows 3:

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
> tcb_clksrc pit jiffies
```

How do they relate?  I played with changing the clock source, but it didn't seem to change anything, why? Where is the system clock and the hardware clock in all of this? Is the rtc hardware used at all?

I'm not afraid to just "roll my own" using ntpdate and adjtimex, but I feel like I just don't have a good understanding of how steady time is supposed to really be accomplished.